# Override a component's default sass variables in a different angular-cli project

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

In a node_module component I have a bunch of sass variables I want to override. For example, a variable in a component that has a !default rule:

`$header-bg: red !default;`

I want to override this variable in my global style sheet in my angular-cli project to blue.

Simply adding `$header-bg: blue;` does not work. What should I do to override those sass variables?

Edit: 
I tried doing the following.

I put the `$header-bg: red !default;` variable into a separate file called overridables.scss and imported that in my global stylesheet file and did like so:

```
$header-bg: blue;

@import "~mypackage/styles/overridables.scss";
```

This didn't work either.

Overriding default variables in Ionic can be done by simply adding the override to our variables.scss. How are they doing it?

Comment: Is it your own component?

Comment: @David Yes, it is an external module. But I created it.

Comment: Maybe that link about overriding material design scss could be helpful: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/05/23/custom-themes-with-angular-material.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi to edit component from `node_modules`, just import it and put in `.angular-cli.json`.

For example, suppose you want to modify bootstrap 4 variables.

**1. Create new file `src/assets/bootstrap/index.scss`:**

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
...
```

this is only copy all file scss from bootstrap.

**2. Create `_variable.scss` in `src/assets/bootstrap`**

Because we want to update the default variable, we need create custom `_variable.scss`. just copy from `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss`

```
//
// Color system
//

// stylelint-disable
$white:    #fff !default;
$gray-100: #f8f9fa !default;
$gray-200: #e9ecef !default;
```

**3. last include `index.scss` to `.angular-cli.json`:**

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "assets/bootstrap/index.scss"
],
```

Now, every time when you want to overwrite default variable from bootstrap, just add to `_variable.scss` and variable default will change.

Comment: In new version of angular cli, I think you need to give styles as ["src/styles.css", "src/assets/bootstrap/index.scss"]

Comment: In our setup, we needed to put variables file before all bootstrap imports (angular 7)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the file using the styles object in `angular.cli` e.g.

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      ...other config here
      "styles": [
        "../styles/overridables.scss",
         ...more css files
        ]
     }
```

I believe the files specified in the styles section of `angular.cli` are applied after the css in the node modules packages.